# Why does $x_t = x^2$ imply $(\frac{1}{x(t,s)})_t=- 1 $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

We have the following transport equation :
$$x^2u_x-(y^2+1)u_y=ux^3$$

Use the method of characteristics to find a solution in $x > 1$ such that $u(1, y) = 2$.

---

The characteristic equations and parametric initial conditions are given by

$$x_t(t,s)=x^2 \:\: y_t(t,s)=-(y^2+1) \:\: u_t(t,s)=ux^3$$
$$x(0,s)=1 \:\: y(0,s)=s \:\: u(0,s)=2$$

Solving for $x$ we get that $x_t = x^2$, so

$$(\frac{1}{x(t,s)})_t=- 1 $$ which implies $$\frac{1}{x(t,s)}- (\frac{1}{x(0,s)}) = -t$$

(...)

---

I have two questions: 
 1) First, why does $x_t = x^2$ imply that $(\frac{1}{x(t,s)})_t=- 1 $ ?

 2) And second, why do they integrate from $0$ to $t$ and not something else ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: $1)$ Because it is a separable first order ODE i.e. $\frac{1}{x^2}dx = dt$.



$2)$ Because we want to know the solution at time $t$ and we have an initial condition at time $0$, so we should integrate between these limits.

Comment: @fGDu94 Just to be sure that I understand well:  If we integrate $\frac{1}{x^2}dx=dt$ on both sides, we get $-\frac{1}{x}=t$, i.e. $\frac{1}{x}=-t$ thus $(\frac{1}{x(t,s)})_t=- 1$ Is that correct ? And should that be trivial to see ?

Comment: yes although there is a constant of integration on the right hand side too. This becomes $\frac{1}{x(0,s)}$ eventually

Comment: @fGDu94 Like $\frac{1}{x(t,s)}=- t + C$ where $C= $ $1\over x(0,s)$ ?

Comment: yes exactly this

Comment: @fGDu94 Okay Thanks. If you want, you can post the information of the comments as an answer so I can accept it and it doesnt appear in the unanswered section anymore. Only if you want of course. Otherwise I will write my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments by @fGDu94:

1) $x_t=x^2$ is a separable first order ODE, i.e. $1/x^2 dx= dt $. So $-1/x = t + (-C)$ i.e. $1/x = -t + C$ thus $1/(x(t,s)_t) = -1 + C$ where $C=1/(x(0,s))$ is a constant of integration.

2) Because we want to know the solution at time  and we have an initial condition at time $0$, so we should integrate between these limits